# Who rules what in Once Upon a Time?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

There are several kings, queens, princes, *etc.* in the magical realm of *Once Upon a Time*, but I’m having trouble keeping them straight. Is there a hierarchy, or are there neighboring kingdoms & principalities?

Who are the various rulers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The Enchanted Forest world

The Enchanted Forest is divided into **kingdoms**.

The ones that are listed during the series are:

- **Evil Queen**'s kingdom (previously ruled by **King Leopold** and **Eva**, i.e., Snow White's parents)
- **King George**'s kingdom (after inherited by **Snow White** and **Prince Charming**, as their kingdom)
- **King Midas**' kingdom (daughter: **Princess Abigail**, who was supposed to marry Prince Charming)
- **King Xavier**'s kingdom (the son, **Prince Henry**, is the Evil Queen's father, married to **Cora**)
- **Cinderella** and **Prince Thomas** kingdom (appears in 1st season)
- **Princess Aurora** and **Prince Philip** kingdom (appears in 2nd season)
- **Prince Eric**'s kingdom (Ariel's true love, ruled previously by his parents; appears in 3rd season)
- **Rapunzel**'s kingdom (ruled by her parents, appears in 3rd season)
- **Elsa**'s kingdom (named ***Arendelle***, as in Disney's *Frozen*)

Moreover, **Sir Maurice** (i.e., Belle's father) owns a castle and speaks about "their kingdom", though it is not clear if he is a prince/king too (still, the fact that he is named as Sir does not qualify him as a prince).

Furthermore, **Maleficent** owns the Forbidden Fortress located in the Enchanted Forest.

### Other worlds

Our world is called **Land without magic**, without any specific ruler. Cited places are:

- Storybrooke
- England (Alice and Wendy Darling are from here)
- New York
- Boston

**Viktor Frankenstein** lives in the **Land without color** (here, all the scenes and characters are in black and white). This is another world with respect to the Enchanted forest, in fact Frankenstein needed the Mad Hatter's hat to travel from here to the Enchanted Forest to follow Rumplestiltskin and find a new magical heart for his brother. The known inhabitants are the Frankenstein family and Igor. No ruler is known from here.

In Once upon a time in Wonderland others appear:

- ***Agrabah***: ruled by Jafar's father, the **Sultan**
- ***Wonderland***: ruled by the **Red Queen**. In fact, this was present in the original Once upon a time plot

Worlds that are cited in the following seasons:

- Season 2 and 3: ***Neverland*** is cited, too. Here, **Peter Pan** is in charge (in fact, he is deciding who comes to and leaves the island)
- Season 5: ***Camelot*** is a land in which ***King Arthur*** reigns
- Season 5: the ***Underworld*** is ruled by **Hades**

***Oz*** is a not-well-commented scenario. It seems that here **Zelena** (i.e., the Wicked Witch) rules somehow, with a reign of terror.

Comment: I think Wonderland and Agrabah were in a different world than the Enchanted Forest, they seemed to need portals to reach those

Comment: This is why I did not enlisted them in the same list of "Enchanted Forest" kingdoms. I would define them other worlds, as it can be the Enchanted Forest, the Land without magic (i.e., our world), Wonderland, Neverland

Comment: Under “Other Worlds”, there’s also Victorian and Edwardian England where Alice and Wendy come from… ☺ (But the rulers are not shown so don’t go adding them to the answer.)

Comment: And, according to the world where Alice and Whendy come from, I guess they are included in the "Land without magic" (our world), since they should be located in London precisely (the Big Ben is always visible during those scenes).

Comment: @Eleanore Time travel is supposed to be impossible, so I understood Alice to be from a different world that looks like ours.  Wendy on the other hand was definitely from our world, given she knew Baelfire

Comment: Arendelle would seem to be in the same world as the Enchanted Forest. I believe at some point it was indicated that one can travel between the two by ship.

Comment: I'll move it, thanks

Comment: @Jonah They explicitly state that the enchanted forest is another world though when Anna goes looking for the reason their parents left.

Comment: http://tvline.com/2015/09/13/once-upon-a-time-season-5-preview-emma-dark-hook-regina-zelena/

Comment: Apparently not only is Arendelle in the same world as the Enchanted Forest, so is Camelot. lolwut?

Comment: "King George's kingdom...  inherited" - what do you mean? King George is alive, why would they inherit it?

Comment: Adam confirmed that Wendy comes from our world: https://twitter.com/adamhorowitzla/status/335785492824068096 And that Alice comes from a fictional Victorian world: https://twitter.com/adamhorowitzla/status/343409032427622400 It makes sense, considering that Baelfire left the Enchanted Forest hundreds of years ago, whereas Once Upon a Time in Wonderland takes place in the modern day.

Answer (score 5):

There are neighboring kingdoms & principalities.

Case in point: The betrothal between King Midas' daughter Princess Abigail and Charming was a political alliance between two neighboring kingdoms.

It helps to think of fairytale land as a fantasy equivalent to medieval-era Europe.